# How to use environment variables in the header of RPM spec file (for Version)?

Tags: rpmbuild

I have a `.spec` file for rpmbuild

```
Name:           my-product
Version:        %{getenv:VERSION}
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        ENTER SUMMARY HERE
Group:          Miscellaneous
License:        Custom
```

I use it in docker and want to run a container with specific environment variables and substitute it in spec file
Is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

You can pass them in as macros:

```
rpmbuild -ba --define "version_ ${VERSION}" myspec.spec
```

Then in the specfile:

```
Version: %{version_}
```

I used the trailing "_" to avoid conflicts with the predefined variables.